# Real time table in Ruby on Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I'm a new user in Ruby on Rails, and I'm very stuck on this. I want to send a POST request with cURL, and display the data received instantly in html without updating the page.

In my controller I have this function:

```
def json
  @users = User.all
  render :json => { :success => true,:users => @users.as_json() }
end
```

In my html:

```
<table class="table">
  <tr>
    <th>Username</th>
    <th>IP</th>
    <th>OS</th>
    <th>Datetime</th>
  </tr>

  <% for user in @users do %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= user.whoami %></td>
    <td><%= user.ip %></td>
    <td><%= user.os %></td>
    <td><%= user.date %></td>
  </tr>
  <% end %>

</table>
```

I've tried with AJAX, but I do not get it.

Comment: You need a websocket connection to enforce an update of the frontend from the backend when curl request comes.

Comment: To elaborate on [mudasobwas comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52497210/real-time-table-in-ruby-on-rails#comment91934774_52497210). Have a look at [Rails Action Cable](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_cable_overview.html).

Comment: I found a simple example: https://melvinchng.github.io/rails/ActionCable.html#21-initial-setup